# What is the meaning of "textScore" in MongoDB FullText Search?

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, full-text-search, nosql

In **mongodb 3.2**, I use commands like this

```
db.articles.find({$text:{$search:”aa bb cc”}},{score:{$meta:”textScore”}}).sort({score:{$meta:”textScore"}})
```

to find familiar text in db. The output is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571449085244bdea9747f631"), "content" : "测试第三次；分号测试", "score" : 0.75 }
```

In my project, I need to know how does **mongodb** generate the score, because I need a percent familiar. I want the output like this in my java project "familiar 50%".
Please tell me how to do this?

Comment: It's **not** an indicator that 50% of the string is matched by the search terms or phrase if that is what you are asking. It's also subject to possible "weighting" in the index definition, so it's not a "set" rule really.

Comment: can u give me an idea to let it output the percent ?

Comment: What I just said is that is **not** how it works. If you want a percentage match then you are better off calculating that with a regex in the client, or possibly applied in mapReduce logic.

Comment: thank u master Neil.